# How to properly specify external make script for existing project with makefile in eclipse c++ ide?

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, external

I am using Eclipse for C++ Luna. I have created a project in eclipse using **New->Makefile Project with Existing Code**. Then I set up targets for this project and they build fine without any changes. Now, instead of running make, I need to run a script that takes the same arguments as make. So I went to project properties and changed **C/C++ Build->Builder Settings** to use a specific build command: `/home/mydir/mycode/mymake.sh`. I also set Build Directory to `/home/mydir/mycode/`.
So when I click on `target1`, in the Eclipse console I see:

```
10:08:48 **** Build of configuration Default for project mycode ****    
/home/mydir/mycode/mymake.sh target1    
10:08:48 Build Finished (took 60ms)
```

So Eclipse can find the script, but in fact the script was not executed (I did check). Could you point me to what I need to do for script to execute from Eclipse? thanks.

Comment: Does your script have the executable bit set?

Comment: Yes it does, without it Eclipse fails explicitly.

Comment: When you said you checked that it wasn't executed what did you mean exactly? Have you inserted debugging print statements into your script (or used `set -x and/or `set -v`) to see if anything in it is run at all?

Comment: I put echo in the script and also tried with set -x as you suggested, but no output except what I put in the question. The title of the console is CDT Build Console [mycode]

Comment: Can you run that exact command in a shell manually? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works manually. Also if I use commands from `/usr/bin/` or `/bin/` they are executed, e.g. `echo, ls, rm` are executed by eclipse if I specify them instead of make in target or C++ builder settings...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63555/discussion-between-bowser-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: As found in chat the issue was an incorrectly written shebang line.